# Measuring heap usage by overriding the C standard library calls

Tags: c++, c++11, malloc, c++14, dynamic-linking

With reference to the following code

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

/*
 * Overload the malloc call
 */
int max_heap_usage = 0;
std::map<uintptr_t, int>& heap_memory_map;
void track_max_usage(std::map<uintptr_t, int> heap_memory_map, 
        int& max_heap_usage);

void* malloc(size_t size) {

    // get the original malloc function call
    static auto original_malloc = (decltype(&malloc)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

    // Get the pointer from malloc
    void* pointer = original_malloc(size);
    uintptr_t pointer_handle = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(pointer);

    // assert that the pointer does not already exist in the memory map
    assert("memory should not exist in memory map before allocation" && 
            heap_memory_map.find(pointer_handle) == heap_memory_map.end());

    // add to bookkeeping
    heap_memory_map[pointer_handle] = size;
    track_max_usage(heap_memory_map, max_heap_usage);

    return pointer;
}

void* calloc(size_t count, size_t size) {

    // get the original calloc
    static auto original_calloc = (decltype(&calloc)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "calloc");

    // get the pointer returned by calloc
    void* pointer = original_calloc(count, size);
    uintptr_t pointer_handle = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(pointer);

    // assert that the memory has not been allocated before
    assert("memory should not exist in the memory map before allocation" && 
            heap_memory_map.find(pointer_handle) == heap_memory_map.end());

    // add to bookkeeping
    heap_memory_map[pointer_handle] = size * count;
    track_max_usage(heap_memory_map, max_heap_usage);

    return pointer;
}

void free(void* ptr) {

    // get the original free function
    static auto original_free = (decltype(&free)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");
    uintptr_t pointer_handle = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr);

    // assert that the heap memory map already has the pointer
    assert("memory to be freed does not exist in the heap memory map" && 
                heap_memory_map.find(pointer_handle) != heap_memory_map.end());

    // add to bookkeeping
    heap_memory_map.erase(pointer_handle);

    // free the memory
    original_free(ptr);
}

/*
 * Inputs:  A map containing pointer values and the amount of heap memory used
 *          after that point
 *
 *          The variable that keeps track of the max memory usage till this
 *          point
 *
 * This function updates the variable to have the max value if the current
 * memory map dictates that the memory usage is greater than what it was
 * before.
 */
void track_max_usage(std::map<uintptr_t, int>& heap_memory_map, 
        int& max_heap_usage) {

    // loop through all keys and add up the values
    int sum {0};
    for (const auto ele : heap_memory_map) { sum += ele.second; }

    // assign to max
    max_heap_usage = std::max(max_heap_usage, sum);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (auto ele : vec) {
        cout << ele << endl;
    }

    cout << "Total heap usage " << max_heap_usage << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to override the malloc, calloc and free calls so that anytime there is a heap allocation I can keep track of it.  Somehow the vector class does not seem to allocate any memory on the heap.  Could someone explain what exactly is going on here?  Also how can I go about achieving the desired result?

Thanks!

Comment: But those have to use malloc behind the scenes.. How else will they allocate memory on the heap?

Comment: Yeah but I think just overriding malloc like you did won't cause them to call your version, they will still call what they use

Comment: How come?  What do I have to do to have them call my function?

Comment: I think you could try replacing `operator new` with a custom declaration as described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new I'm not entirely sure if the default `vector` allocator will see the replaced version, though.

Comment: You have a problem that map insertion might call malloc, leading to recursion.

Comment: I do not think this has anything to do with namespaces,  the namespace is resolved to a symbol prefix when code gets compiled.  Maybe marking it with extern C will help though.  I will try that now

Comment: @Dani you are correct!  How would you recommend I go about fixing that?

Comment: Nope extern "C" did not fix this...

Comment: @Curious, suppose that `std::vector` is calling directly malloc, then surely it is including `cstdlib` or similar, right? But then what happens to your alternate definition? It is clobbered? Or shadowed? Either way it doesn't sound kosher to me.

Comment: @ChrisBeck You are correct but I do not believe that is how linking works.  The vector library calls "malloc", it does not define it.  After the dynamic linking there should be two malloc calls and the vector library should call mine right?  Please let me know if I am wrong though.  I think I might be confused about how this stuff is working

Comment: You can fix it by using a thread local flag that you raise at entry to the the hooks and lower when you exit. If you enter the function with it raised, just call the original without the insertion.

Comment: @Curious: `operator new` is specifically described as "user-replaceable" [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), I think that's the intended way to do what you are trying to do. I don't have access to my copy of the standard on this machine but I would doubt if any C standard library functions are possible to replace like this, by contrast.

Comment: Your vector is not using heap allocation here `vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4};`.

Comment: @Dani +1 for the thread local idea!  I missed it when programming.

Comment: @Curious: It's allocated on the stack that way, because there is no `new` operator called. Heap allocation would look like `std::vector<int>* vec =  new std::vector<int>({1,2,3,4});`. But then you also will need an explicit call to `delete vec;`

Comment: @cwschmidt I believe that is incorrect.  Unless there is a short-string-esque optimization in the vector class, the initializer list constructor for the vector class probably calls the operator new to allocate its array.

Comment: "You are correct but I do not believe that is how linking works." I'm not completely sure, but if you are hoping that ambiguity is resolved at linking, it's probably an ODR violation. The linker's job is just sew up all the links it can find without getting bogged down. Ambiguous / overloaded names are handled by name mangling. I don't know if your program breaks ODR because I don't know if the standard `malloc` definition is technically in it for purposes of ODR. Maybe its statically linked into stdlib and not visible to linker. But if not then I think it is an ODR violation and you have UB.

Comment: I guess another possible interpretation of your program is: You define `malloc`, `calloc`, `free`, then you declare a tracking function and `main`, none of which call `malloc`, `calloc`, or `free`. You are hoping that `std::vector` calls those functions, but I think it actually calls `operator new` which refers to some implementation in the stdlib. So those symbols you defined are not ODR used and get stripped from the program. (?) And the linker never sees them and you don't get UB.

Comment: @Curious: Do you have any sources for that assumption? You use the wording "I believe" and "probably". Can't it be just implementation dependent (e.g. allocation type changes depending on the actual size of the vector, etc)?
Anyway, to proof what you want to proof, I would allocate something explicitly on the heap (instead to try to rely on assumptions). Therefore I mentioned that the "vec" was not allocated on the heap. That it might or might not use heap allocation internally was not (intentionally) subject of my reply above.

Comment: @cwschmidt You said "Your vector is not using heap allocation here", that does not clearly imply what you were intending to say.  In fact it is correct to expand your sentence to be implying "Your vector is not using heap allocation internally in this statement".  It could have been disambiguated if you had said "Your program is not allocating `vec` on the heap".

Comment: @cwschmidt The vector class internally does call new in that case.

Comment: @Curious: Therefore my subsequent comment after yours. Editing comments is only possible for a short period of time. And **I couldn't not see in advance that my comment is not clear for you**. What I wanted to tell you is (also stated in my second comment): Allocate something explicitly on the heap instead of relying on assumptions.

Comment: @Curious: "The vector class internally does call new in that case." Might be true for the implementation on your platform, might be true or not for other platforms (especially embedded systems). With that statement being true it would also imply that all other potential implementations of vector not using `new` internally will be wrong. Again, can you give a source for such an assumption?

Comment: @cwschmidt You are right.  I was only applying that this happens on both my Ubuntu and Mac OS computers

Answer (score 5):

Your program as posted - call it `main.cpp` - does not quite compile, so it can't be quite
the program whose disappointing behaviour you would like explained:

```
error: 'heap_memory_map' declared as reference but not initialized
 std::map<uintptr_t, int>& heap_memory_map;
                       ^
```

And if we fix that by declaring instead:

```
std::map<uintptr_t, int> heap_memory_map;
```

we then have a linkage error:

```
undefined reference to `track_max_usage(std::map<unsigned long, int, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> > >, int&)'
```

because the declaration:

```
void track_max_usage(std::map<uintptr_t, int> heap_memory_map, 
        int& max_heap_usage);
```

does not match the definition:

```
void track_max_usage(std::map<uintptr_t, int>& heap_memory_map, 
        int& max_heap_usage) {
    ...
}
```

If we fix that also by declaring:

```
void track_max_usage(std::map<uintptr_t, int>& heap_memory_map, 
        int& max_heap_usage);
```

then we successfully compile and link, at least if we're not fussy
about standard conformance:

```
$ g++ -o prog -std=c++11 -Wall main.cpp -ldl
```

If we *are* fussy about Standard conformance:

```
$ g++ -o prog -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -ldl
```

then there remain compilation *errors*:

```
main.cpp:20:25: error: declaration of ‘void* malloc(size_t)’ has a different exception specifier
 void* malloc(size_t size) {
                         ^
...
/usr/include/stdlib.h:466:14: error: from previous declaration ‘void* malloc(size_t) throw ()’
 extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__ __wur;
              ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void* calloc(size_t, size_t)’:
main.cpp:40:39: error: declaration of ‘void* calloc(size_t, size_t)’ has a different exception specifier
 void* calloc(size_t count, size_t size) {
                                       ^
...
/usr/include/stdlib.h:468:14: error: from previous declaration ‘void* calloc(size_t, size_t) throw ()’
 extern void *calloc (size_t __nmemb, size_t __size)
              ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void free(void*)’:
main.cpp:60:20: error: declaration of ‘void free(void*)’ has a different exception specifier
 void free(void* ptr) {
                    ^
...
/usr/include/stdlib.h:483:13: error: from previous declaration ‘void free(void*) throw ()’
 extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
```

Another couple of passing carps:

`int` isn't guaranteed to store the size of heap block. Thus the Standard library says:

```
void* malloc(size_t size);
void* calloc(size_t num, size_t size);
```

and not:

```
void* malloc(int size);
void* calloc(int num, int size);
```

So by rights you'd have:

```
size_t max_heap_usage = 0;
std::map<uintptr_t, size_t> heap_memory_map;
```

Further, what you actually want is a map of `void *`-values to sizes,
and there's no reason at all not to have such a map:

```
std::map<void *, size_t> heap_memory_map;
```

Then the refrain:

```
uintptr_t pointer_handle = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(pointer);
```

could be dispensed with.

Going with what we've got however (and remembering that we don't
know exactly what *you* have got) running `prog` does not simply
fail to tally any heap allocations; it crashes:

```
$ ./prog
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If you debug this and peruse the backtrace to the segfault, you'll
see the circular call sequence:

```
operator new(unsigned long)    
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> > >::allocate  /usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h  104
std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> > > >::allocate  /usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h  360
std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> >, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> > >::_M_get_node  /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h  491
std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> >, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> > >::_M_create_node<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<unsigned long const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<unsigned long const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&)  /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h  545
std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> >, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> > >::_M_emplace_hint_unique<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<unsigned long const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<unsigned long const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&)  /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h  2170
std::map<unsigned long, int, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> > >::operator[]  /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h  483
malloc  /home/imk/develop/so/heap_track_orig/main.cpp  34
operator new(unsigned long)
```

repeated *ad nauseam*. So the program is looping until it runs out of stack.

This is due to a fatal logical flaw. You're proceeding on the assumption that all the C++ dynamic memory management
operations in the program will be delegated to the Standard C library facilities
`malloc`, `calloc` and `free`.

Well, at least some of them are, and in particular the calls to `operator new`
that originate in

```
heap_memory_map[pointer_handle] = size;
```

when you allocate a new element of your heap map are delegated to `malloc`.
Which is *your* `malloc`. Which again calls:

```
heap_memory_map[pointer_handle] = size;
```

then `operator new`, then back to `malloc`, and so on to stack-exhaustion.

That is the fatal logical flaw, but the motivating assumption is also flaky.
The C++ Standard does not require even the default implementations of `operator new` and
`operator delete` to delegate respectively to `malloc` and `free`. It doesn't
specify any relationship between dynamic memory management in C++ and that of C.
The C++ compiler I'm using here (Linux, GCC) does in fact so delegate, and
probably so does yours, but an implementor might choose to delegate both
`malloc/free` and `new/delete` directly to OS APIs.

Don't attempt to roll your own heap-profiling. Use a proper heap-profiler.
For linux, the go-to heap profiler is [Valgrind's](http://valgrind.org/) [`massif`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html).
Your distro will almost certainly provide a Valgrind package, including `massif`.

Here's a program that I'm going to profile with `massif` and check it's max heap usage:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    for (   ;vec.size(); vec.pop_back()) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and link:

```
$ g++ -g -o prog -Wall main.cpp
```

Run `valgrind` with `massif`:

```
$ valgrind --tool=massif ./prog
==6479== Massif, a heap profiler
==6479== Copyright (C) 2003-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote
==6479== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6479== Command: ./prog
==6479== 
==6479==
```

The heap-profile is output by default in `massif.out.NNNN`. I find `massif.out.6479`
and run:

```
$ ms_print massif.out.6479 > heap_prof.txt
```

I look in `heap_prof.txt` and at line 32 I read:

```
Number of snapshots: 29
 Detailed snapshots: [4, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26 (peak)]
```

which tells me that heap snapshot #26 shows the peak usage. I scroll to
snapshot #26 and see:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 24      2,049,029           74,768           74,752            16            0
 25      2,069,629           78,872           78,848            24            0
 26      2,070,679           78,872           78,848            24            0
99.97% (78,848B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->92.18% (72,704B) 0x4EB91FE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| ->92.18% (72,704B) 0x4010608: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
|   ->92.18% (72,704B) 0x4010719: _dl_init (dl-init.c:30)
|     ->92.18% (72,704B) 0x4000D08: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so)
|       
->07.79% (6,144B) 0x401788: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
  ->07.79% (6,144B) 0x401665: __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:182)
    ->07.79% (6,144B) 0x4014B0: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:170)
      ->07.79% (6,144B) 0x400F59: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (vector.tcc:353)
        ->07.79% (6,144B) 0x400CC4: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_vector.h:925)
          ->07.79% (6,144B) 0x400AEC: main (main.cpp:9)
```

So the program's top recorded heap consumption was 78,872 bytes, of
which (a mere) 6,144 bytes were allocated for my `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard library containers don't use `malloc` and such directly, they use "allocator" objects, which are generally provided as a template parameter. You can look at providing a custom allocator, or, providing a custom `operator new` function, if you want to hook into things like this for measurement purposes.